# java.lang.NullPointerException (Unknown Source)

Tags: android

I can not figure out this problem , I have no info what happens ! I get this error from my google apps panel.Do not be referred to this.

This is the error in google publish:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     
     ComponentInfo{es.project/es.project.activity.ChatActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.project.activity.ChatActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    ... 11 more
```

In my emulator this code works , but I think some people have errors in. This is my OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    serverId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("serverId");
    server = Chatsi.getInstance().getServerById(serverId);
    Settings settings = new Settings(this);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    setTitle("");
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);        
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    input.setOnKeyListener(inputKeyListener);
    //INDICATOR
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ConversationPagerAdapter(this, server);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    indicator = (ConversationIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titleIndicator);
    indicator.setServer(server);
    indicator.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    indicator.setFooterColor(0xFFFF8800);
    indicator.setFooterLineHeight(2 * density);
    indicator.setFooterIndicatorHeight(4 * density);
    indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Underline);
    indicator.setSelectedColor(0xFF000000);
    indicator.setSelectedBold(true);
    indicator.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF2F2F2);
    indicator.setTextColor(0xFF222222);
    //Botones
    Button boton1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    boton1.setOnClickListener(mandartexto); 
    Button boton2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.emoticonos);
    boton2.setOnClickListener(mandaremoticon); 
    Button boton3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.lupa);
    boton3.setOnClickListener(mandarlupa); 
    //MENUS
    menuview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuview);
    MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, BOTONES);
    menuview.setAdapter(menuAdapter); 

    historySize = settings.getHistorySize();

    if (server.getStatus() == Status.PRE_CONNECTING) {
        server.clearConversations();
        pagerAdapter.clearConversations();
        server.getConversation(ServerInfo.DEFAULT_NAME).setHistorySize(historySize);
    }

    float fontSize = settings.getFontSize();
    indicator.setTextSize(fontSize * density);

    input.setTextSize(settings.getFontSize());
    input.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

    // Optimization : cache field lookups
    Collection<Conversation> mConversations = server.getConversations();

    for (Conversation conversation : mConversations) {
        // Only scroll to new conversation if it was selected before
        if (conversation.getStatus() == Conversation.STATUS_SELECTED) {
            onNewConversation(conversation.getName());
        } else {
            createNewConversation(conversation.getName());
        }
    }

    scrollback = new Scrollback();
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear,R.anim.disappear);

}
```

Comment: On what line? Help us out here

Comment: It might be possible that your onCreate is taking too much time to execute, I had a similar issue on low end devices. have you tried moving some of the code to onResume() where possible?

Comment: Remyoman@ tell me I should move, my OnResume is very extensive Tim Castelijns@ I dont  know  the line, the debug not inform me

Comment: @Remyoman - no, this is clearly a null pointer exception not a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

```
server = Chatsi.getInstance().getServerById(serverId);
```

and then

```
if (server.getStatus() == Status.PRE_CONNECTING) {
```

Form one **of potentially many examples** of places where a trivial failure to obtain an object (due to anything from temporarily poor signal strength on up) has the potential to result in an uncaught Null Pointer Exception.

Whenever you obtain an object form a mechanism *that could fail*, you should either check that the object is non-null before you utilize it, or protect your attempt to utilize it with a try/catch block or higher level handler which can recover from the exception.

The problem is not necessarily with your server object - it could be your view or anything else which is *obtained by a mechanism which can fail*, or used in a code pathway *which may not have yet initialized it*.

Comment: what you say  can not help my